# I'm under 18, Can I upload my projects to Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

Actually I'm an Android Developer from India, I want to create a Google Play Console ID and upload apps on Google Play Store but I am under 18 i.e. My age is 15 years, so can I upload my projects to Google Play Store?? If yes How????

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about managing a business relationship, communicating between the question OP and a third party, and/or dealing with a legal issue. In other words, it's not about programming as defined in the [help/on-topic]. You might be able to get help from the Customer Service for the company you are interfacing with. If you want an interpretation of legal requirements, it might be appropriate to ask on [law.se].

Answer (score 1):

[The Google Play Console required 18 years old or older at all time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Lyvf.png)

You need to wait for your 18th Birthday to create a Google Play Console ID and upload apps on Google Play Store. I am 18 years old that lived in Oklahoma City, USA from Beijing, China.