# Can I make a google developer account if I am under 18?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-development

I started making games a little bit back, and want to release my first one. I was doing research, and was disappointed when I figured out google required me to be at least 18 years of age. I researched the problem further and had a few StackOverflow answers that told me different things. I heard that I *could* make the account if I had permission from a parent or legal guardian. Is this false? One answer told me that I could publish without an age restriction as long as I made no profit (no ads). Is there a way of publishing my apps to the google play store, preferably with ads, when I am under 18? Could I get parent/guardian permission?

Here are the posts:

- [one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58301649/im-under-18-can-i-upload-my-projects-to-google-play-store)
- [another one](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/100709/how-do-i-publish-to-google-play-if-im-under-18)

If publishing to google play store is impossible without being over 18, do you have any recommendations for where to publish my games (if I can at all).

Please don’t recommend other publishing websites unless that is the only way. Please provide links to google or something trusted and thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, Welcome to stack overflow, if you already found a post about it you can ask for help there, no need to create a new post. any way, I will try to help with my answer

Comment: I saw that thread, and there are two different answers. I don’t know which one to believe. You may say the one with 2 more upvotes, but I can’t be sure.

Comment: Is it possible for a parent/guardian to create the account, and I publish the games?

Comment: Always go with the one with upvotes and not the one with the down votes, any way as I said in my answer, yes you can

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you saw the posts you added, the ruled of that platform say that you can't.

The simple way is just to ask your parents/guardian to create it for you and just use this account. Google doesn't know who is uploading the apps.

Comment: i like this smart answer. hehe

Comment: Thanks you, I try to be :D

Comment: Not related to my question, but do you know why they require certain ages? I mean legally. Does it even have to do with law?

Comment: Problem money and privacy laws around the world

Comment: @ken You have to be above the age of majority (18+ in the US except in three states) to be able to be bound to a contract.

Comment: @Benjamin I don’t quite understand what you are saying

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. You should be 18.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am going to see if anyone tells me different, and see what they have to say.

Comment: Google clearly says you have to be 18, so I am not sure why you're looking for a second opinion. Regardless of what they say, you know that it's not allowed.